# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I have this partial code:

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbC = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cbC.HeaderText = "Code:";
        cbC.Name = "code";
        cbC.ContextMenuStrip = mymenu;(is a ContextMenuStrip)
```

I click with right mouse button on the row but the menu not showing, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your DataGridView properties, there is an option called "ContextMenuStrip" (at "Behavior"). Select your ContextMenuStrip and it should work.
[image: property screenshot]

Alternatively you can add this line of code in the designer (**not recommended!**):

```
//
// dataGridView1
//
...
this.dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1
...
```

**EDIT**
This way the ContextMenu is everywhere. You can add it for each column seperately by right-clicking the DataGridView (in the editor) and then "Edit Columns...".
As before you can add it in the designer via code (**also not recommended**):

```
// 
// Column1
// 
this.Column1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
...
```

Comment: This is my code (from my post):
cbC.ContextMenuStrip = mymenu;(is a ContextMenuStrip)
This is the your code;
this.Column1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
Where is the difference?

Comment: @Frank - Did you try adding it via GUI? This way it should work. The only difference I see is that you don't have `this.` ...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here, you will find the answer :)

[DataGridViewColumn.ContextMenuStrip propriété](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx)